# How to implement pagination in firebase realtime database like we can implement in SQL?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pagination

I am creating an admin app and it requires to list the products saved in my firebase realtime database. As there can be hundreds of products and they can not be listed on single page so i have to implement pagination. I have found a way to implement pagination as described in official documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data).

By using *startAt()* and *limitToFirst()* I can jump forward in pages and by using *endAt()* and *limitToLast()* I can jump backward in pages. This way I can jump between consecutive pages. e.g

Page 1 <-> Page 2 <-> Page 3 <-> Page 4

For forward jumping in pages

```
firebase.db.ref("products")
  .orderByKey()
  .limitToFirst(pageSize + 1)
  .startAt(lastKey)
```

For backward jumping in pages

```
firebase.db.ref("products")
  .orderByKey()
  .limitToLast(pageSize + 1)
  .endAt(firstKey)
```

In above code snippets **pageSize** is the number of products to be displayed in a page, **lastKey** is the key of the last product from the results of previous page query (which will be empty in case of first page) and **firstKey** is the key of first product from the results of previous page query.

But the problem is that if I have to jump directly from Page 1 to Page 3 then I couldn't find a way to achieve that. This is sort of what I want;

Page 1 <-> Page 3 <-> Page 6

Can anybody guide me is that possible to do in firebase realtime database, if yes then how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase's query model is anchor-based, and not offset-based. That makes it less suitable for random access pagination, and more suitable for infinite-scroll type lazy loading.

To load a page you will need to know the key if the first or last item on that page. There is no way to jump to a page by its offset, you will have to know one of the keys.

The (long since deprecated) `firebase-utils` library implemented pagination by first loading all keys via the REST API (which allows loading keys without loading their values), and then using that to find the start and end of every page. But that'd mean that you miss realtime updates, which feels a bit like a waste when using Firebase.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot :)