# How to get child keys from Firebase Realtime DB with pagination

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

I need to get keys from Firebase Realtime DB. Here is an example structure:

Example:

```
persons
    p1
        first_ name: John
        surname: Blue
    p2
        first_ name: Johnny
        surname: Red
    p3
        first_ name: Mike
        surname: Orange
```

So, I need to get [p1, p2, p3] as a list.

But the challenge is that this list is quite big, with more than 10K nodes. So, the list will actually look something like `[p1, p2, . . . , p11000]`.

```
def get_keys_only(db_path):
    ref = db.reference(db_path) 

    # first arg must be False for shallow queries
    # ref.get(includeEtag, shallowQuery)
    valueAtRef_as_dict = ref.get(False, True)

    # The returned data can be None if the collection doesn't exist in DB
    if valueAtRef_as_dict is not None:
        # Keys returned in a list
        return_list = [*valueAtRef_as_dict]
    else:
        return_list = []

    return return_list
```

But it throws `firebase_admin.exceptions.UnavailableError` exception. Here is the details:

```
in get_keys_only valueAtRef_as_dict = ref.get(False, True) File "/usr/local
/lib/python3.8/site-packages/firebase_admin/db.py", line 221, in get return 
self._client.body('get', self._add_suffix(), params=params) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/firebase_admin/_http_client.py", line 131, 
in body resp = self.request(method, url, **kwargs) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/firebase_admin/db.py", 
line 931, in request raise _Client.handle_rtdb_error(error) 
firebase_admin.exceptions.UnavailableError: Request has timed out
```

I have run some tests on other Realtime DB nodes in my database and the code seems to work fine when the returned list is small. I suspect that I need to use pagination but I don't know how.

How can I use pagination to make this code work when retrieving large number of keys from Firebase Realtime DB? If pagination will not work, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement pagination in firebase realtime database like we can implement in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57200971/how-to-implement-pagination-in-firebase-realtime-database-like-we-can-implement)

Comment: Thanks for your comment but that does not answer my question. That answer downloads data from all the child nodes. Downloading data from child nodes is not an option in my case because the amount of data is quite big and it will be extremely costly to do it so. I only need to get "keys" but it fails probably bcz the number of keys is too big. Both Firestore and Realtime DBs are really just for high school projects.

Comment: Can you give us some more information? 1. What library are you using or you are open to achieving the same using RESTful API?

Comment: @KayvanShah I am sorry but I could not clearly understand what exactly you are asking. Would you be able to provide some instructions?

Comment: Let me know if you find the answer userful

Answer (score 0):

To paginate you can apply this approach

##### Sample Data

```json
{
  "persons" : {
    "p1" : {
      "first_name" : "John",
      "surname" : "Wick"
    },
    "p2" : {
      "first_name" : "Ram",
      "surname" : "Manohar"
    },
    "p3" : {
      "first_name" : "Mike",
      "surname" : "Orange"
    }
  }
}
```

##### Method and assumptions

- Assuming that all the person keys start with `p`
- Order the data by `$key` at the persons level
- Use the `startAt` and `endAt` filters on top of the `orderBy` to get the desired pagination result.
- We can now translate this to a generic python template when keeping the `p` fixed and varying the `id` in `f"p{id}"` i.e is in your case belongs to `{p1, p2, p3, ... pN}`
- Batch over the keys with optimal batch size (N), for eg. N=100 and stop when you receiver `None` as a response

##### Example 1

```bash
~$ curl 'https://test-5681a-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/persons.json?orderBy="$key"&startAt="p1"&endAt="p2"&print=pretty'
> {
  "p1" : {
    "first_name" : "John",
    "surname" : "Wick"
  },
  "p2" : {
    "first_name" : "Ram",
    "surname" : "Manohar"
  }
}
```

##### Example 2

```bash
~$ curl 'https://test-5681a-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/persons.json?orderBy="$key"&startAt="p2"&endAt="p3"&print=pretty'
{
  "p2" : {
    "first_name" : "Ram",
    "surname" : "Manohar"
  },
  "p3" : {
    "first_name" : "Mike",
    "surname" : "Orange"
  }
}
```

##### Reference to Official Firebase Realtime DB's documentation

- [orderBy="$key"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#filtering-by-key)
- [startAt & endAt filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#range-queries)

Comment: You won't be able to use `shallow=True` when using filters

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this approach as well but since it is not possible to use the shallow=True (as you mentioned in the comment), it is not a solution to my problem. The keys need to be retrieved quite often and downloading the underlying child data will just increase the costs totally unnecessarily while impacting the performance very negatively.

Comment: I posted my answer wrt to the REST API that I have used. Did you also try the same with Python SDK?